# How can I ask apache shiro about object ids

Tags: shiro

Given a subject that has the following permissions:

```
printer:1:manage  
printer:2:manage  
printer:3:admin  
printer:1:print
printer:4:print
```

I know I can ask if:

```
subject.isPermitted('printer:1:manage')
```

But how do i ask shiro questions such as:

- For which printer id's does the subject has a "manage" permission? (I want the answer 1,2)
- For which printer id's does the subject has a permission (or any kind)? (I want the answer 1,2,3)
- For which printer id's does the subject has a manage or admin permission? (I want the answer 1,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Shiro's API only provides checks and assertions for permissions or roles; it does not provide any finder methods to look up what a Subject has permissions to, or to look up which Subjects have permission to something.

You could explore implementing your own `findPermissions()` in your `AuthorizingRealm` that takes a *query permission* and collects all available permissions for the Subject where `queryPermission.implies(grantedPermission)` returns `true`, somewhat along these lines:

```java
protected Collection<Permission> findPermissions(Permission queryPermission, AuthorizationInfo info) {
    Collection<Permission> foundPermissions;
    Collection<Permission> perms = getPermissions(info);

    if (perms != null && !perms.isEmpty()) {
        foundPermissions = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        for (Permission perm : perms) {
            if (queryPermission.implies(perm)) {
                foundPermissions.add(perm);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        foundPermissions = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return foundPermissions;
}
```

*Note that this is the inverse `implies` relationship to how `AuthorizingRealm.isPermitted()` performs its check.*

If you aren't committed to Apache Shiro, yet, the open-source [OACC security framework](http://oaccframework.org) *(disclosure: I'm maintainer and co-author)* actually features efficient symmetric query methods to find both the permissions on resources, as well as which resources have permission to something, without you having to implement anything.

Comment: thanks,I have implemented my own functionalty for getting the related instance id (outside of shiro). I will also have a look at your framework.